# Composer revert after making changes

Tags: drupal, mercurial, composer-php, revert

I am using composer to manage dependencies in a Drupal project. Some modules I have are in mercurial repositories. Once I do `composer install` I am able to download my Drupal modules from their respective mercurial repositories. The composer.lock file also gets generated correctly.

Now let's say I make changes in one of the repositories. After that, if I run `composer install`, I expect the changes to get reverted, so that the repository goes back to the revision stored in composer.lock.

But that does not happen. The changes I have made persist. Am I missing something? Is this because am using a mercurial repository?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand this correctly, you change something in your `vendor/project` and you want to revert there changes, right?
If so, I usually remove `vendor/project` directory and install package again.

Comment: Yup that's right. I made some local changes to my `vendor/project` and I would like to revert those changes. What you are suggesting works but is not feasible. I may have made local changes in several of my packages, and I want to revert all of them. Would it not be simpler to do this through the command line? I am wondering why `composer install` does not revert?

Comment: There no command to revert changes when package version has not changed. If there is newer version, composer asks you what to do about them. That's why the best, fastest and most reliable way is to remove them manually and then install.